# /etc/hostname vs /etc/hosts vs /etc/sysconfig/network in centos7

Tags: linux, centos

I find that I can put different hostnames in following three files. Can anyone help explain when and how to use each of them? It is a CentOS7 box.

```
/etc/hostname # run command hostname - I suspect this is the actual hostname

/etc/hosts #for 127.0.0.1 only?

/etc/sysconfig/network
```

Comment: These man pages help to understand these files: `man 5 hosts`,  `man 5 hostname` and `man 5 networks`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` is for defining your own domain names for certain IP addresses. It commonly has this entry:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

That means that `localhost`, when used in a browser or other program that accesses the internet, should be directed to `127.0.0.1`. It's like having your own local DNS server (that nobody else can use). You can also add more than one name:

```
127.0.0.1   local localhost
```

And it doesn't need to be just 127.0.0.1. You can put any number of names to whatever IP addresses you want.

---

`/etc/hostname` is how you [specify your computer’s hostname](https://serverfault.com/a/228111). That is used for many things such as in Bluetooth-enabled computers, that’s the name other devices see. There are a lot of other uses; I recommend you take a look at that Server Fault post I linked. As mentioned by ivanivan, your hostname should be resolvable, so that should be in `/etc/hosts` next to `localhost`.

---

> The `/etc/sysconfig/network` file is used to specify information about the desired network configuration.

<sub><sup>(https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-network.html)</sup></sub>

I’ve actually never seen this file before (I run Debian, not CentOS), but it appears to be basically a broader form of `/etc/hostname` that lets you set more options. It appears that it is also newer than `/etc/hostname`, but `/etc/hostname` is still there to support older software.

Comment: Have I said something wrong that I deserve a downvote? A comment would help me a lot more if I did.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  I think this answer is fairly (but if I'm a pedant, not exactly) correct and explains the differences nicely.

Comment: And whatever is in /etc/hostname should be resolvable so put it in /etc/hosts with a reference to 127.0.0.1